# Meaning of vitative(ness)

Tags: meaning

I've seen the word *vitativeness* used in a book about the history of writing, referring to a list of descriptive words written in 1900. 
Vitative(ness) is not in my Oxford dictionary, nor dictionary.com.  What does it mean?

Comment: I recommend using [onelook](http://www.onelook.com/?loc=rescb&refclue=fond&w=vitative) when your usual dictionaries fail you.

Comment: Yes, while onelook is no match for a full OED, the ability to compare different definitions quickly is a great tool, especially as some of the specialist dictionaries give a new insight (though they include Urban Dictionary, which needs several pinches of salt).

Comment: Onelook has got some great pattern searching options too, e.g. "[vita*:life](http://www.onelook.com/?w=vita*%3Alife&ls=a)" gives words starting "vita" related to "life"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Vitativeness* is in the Oxford English Dictionary, where it is described as a term used in phrenology (the scientific study of the mind). The meaning is given as ‘the love of life, the desire to live, regarded as a special faculty of the mind or brain.’ There are two supporting citations from the nineteenth century.

Comment: Thanks, Barrie. My Oxford at home is not the huge two volume edition.

Comment: I use the online OED at http://www.oed.com/. It requires a paid subscription, but it's free in the UK to those who have a public library card.

Comment: And if you decide to splash out on the full set, the online is more up to date than the print, so unless you want the luxury of the leather bound edition (and hey, if you're splashing out that much, why not go for both versions!), it's a good investment. It's not cheap though, so I tend to have it quarters I'm a bit flush, and not otherwise.

Comment: @Jon Hanna. Irish libraries not so generous then?

Comment: I think they are, but I'm not so flexible as to when I urgently want to track down a word, especially since I do most of my writing at night.

Comment: Oh wait, you mean where you can log-in from anywhere with your library card number? Most don't, though some college libraries do. I think even some UK libraries don't. Maybe I should rejoin my childhood library when I next visit the North. Generally, I buy books rather than borrow as I can afford to add to my home library at a faster rate than I can read, but saving that subscription would be worthwhile.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I believe all county libraries in the UK offer the service. It might be worth inquiring whether libraries in Ireland do too.